# When to use an owned entity types vs just creating a foreign key or adding the columns directly to the table?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I was reading about owned entity types here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#feedback and I was wondering when I would use that. Especially when using `.ToTable();` although I am not sure if ToTable creates a relationship with keys.

I read the entire article so I understand that it essentially forces you to access the data via nav properties and prevents the owned table from being treated as an entity. They also say `Include()` is not needed and the data comes down with every query for the parent table so its not like you are reducing the amount of data that comes back.

So whats the point exactly? Also whats the point of "table splitting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the place of Complex types with the option to set it up like a 1-1 relationship /w ToTable while automatically eager-loaded. This would use the same PK in both tables, same as 1-1.

The point Table-splitting would be that you want an object model that is normalized, where the table structure is not. This would fit scenarios where you have an existing table structure and want to split off related pieces of that data into sub-entities associated with the main entity. With the ToTable option, it would be similar to a 1-1 relationship, but automatically eager-loaded. However when considering the reasons to use a 1-1 relationship I would consider this option a bad choice.

The common reasons for using it in normal 1-1 relationships would include:

- Splitting off expensive to load, rarely used data. (images, binary, memo)
- Encapsulating data particular to a single application off of a common entity. i.e. if I have a "Customer" which is used by a billing system vs. a CRM I might have "CustomerBillingData" and "CustomerCRMData" owned by "Customer" rather than an inherited BillingCustomer / CRMCustomer. As there is a "single" customer that may serve one or both systems. Billing doesn't care about CRM data, CRM doesn't care about Billing. If all data is in "Customer" then both systems potentially need to be updated, and I cannot rely on constraints when the data is optional to the other system. By using composition I can enforce required data for a particular system.

In neither of these cases would I want to use table-splitting or anything that automatically eager-loads, so Owned Types /w ToTable would not replace 1-1 relationships by any stretch. It's essentially a more strict version of complex types, I'd say it's strictly used for entity organization. Not something I'd admit to wanting to use very often.

Comment: Also they are a good way to model DDD Value Objects, so basically anywhere you might use value objects this feature may prove useful.